# Session lost in sub domain url in apache server

Tags: php

I have a session lost problem in sub domain url (test.example.com) after login. But the same code working fine in (i.e example.com). I tried session.cookie_domain but same error exist. Please anybody help in this regards

Answer (score -1):

I had the same experience like you hundreds of times which I finally found the problem. You don't need to worry if cookies enable or disable. You just have to re-declare parts of your scripts (variables-the data which you want to display) in a if else condition. Just redeclare the same thing using !isset and then else with the same variables mentioned twice in the if else condition, if you understand what i mean.e.g if (!isset etc){A+B}  else {A+B}. It will call back the same variables over and over. And make sure start session is above the page and define a session e.g session['id'] on that page which you claim missing.. no need to worry about headers or white lines, it has actually nothing to do with it. I've tried it a million times. You don't need to bother using ajax etc. PHP can do almost everything. cheerio.